# 'Response' object has no attribute 'soup' in kaggle cli

Tags: dataset, kaggle

I was using kaggle-cli, when I run kg download I get the above mentioned error.

Here is the code I am posting:

kg download -c 'instacart-market-basket-analysis'

I don't need to give my username and password because I am already logged in and I don't want to give a file name because I want all of the data.
Please also note that my kaggle-cli and pip are all up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the officially supported [Kaggle API](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api) instead. Once you've got it set up ([you can find step-by-step instructions here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/upload-update-data-kaggle-api/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#1)), you can download all the files in the competition like so:

```
kaggle competitions download -c instacart-market-basket-analysis
```

Note that, just like with the unofficial Kaggle CLI, you will have to accept the competition rules before you can download the data for that competition.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @Racheal, official kaggle API's download command is not resumable while kaggle-cli has this feature. See [this](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api/issues/24), it would be awesome if you could get this feature implemented :)